# Python mechanize error in open

Tags: python, mechanize

I have problem with mechanize. From today mechanize don't want to open this site:

```
url = "http://dom.gratka.pl/"
```

It's interesting, because it's worked fine.

This is my code:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

br = mechanize.Browser()

br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=10)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US;     rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

url = "http://dom.gratka.pl/"
parsehtml = br.open(url)
```

I have a specific error and I don't know what I am doing wrong

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    parsehtml = br.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 230, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_opener.py", line 204, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_http.py", line 201, in http_response
    self.head_parser_class())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_http.py", line 171, in parse_head
    parser.feed(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_sgmllib_copy.py", line 110, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_sgmllib_copy.py", line 192, in goahead
    self.handle_charref(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_http.py", line 80, in handle_charref
    self.handle_data(unescape_charref(name, self._encoding))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_html.py", line 317, in unescape_charref
    uc = unichr(int(name, base))
ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)
```